# Why do eyeglasses use meniscus lenses?

Tags: optics, lenses, vision

Any eyeglasses prescription could be filled exactly with "symmetrically-shaped" lenses.
E.g., a far-sighted person could use a symmetric biconvex lens (i.e., the normal "magnifying glass"), or a near-sighted person could use a symmetric biconcave lens.

So, why do opticians prefer the meniscus style (where the outward side is always convex and the inward side is always concave)?  Is there a non-aesthetic optics/vision benefit?

You can assume no astigmatism, but I'd like an answer which works for both far-sighted and
near-sighted people.

Comment: When I look up meniscus lenses I find that it's not as widely used as you seem to believe. Where did you gather that most glasses are of this lens style?

Comment: They [reduce aberration](https://www.google.com/search?q=meniscus+lens+aberration).

Comment: @JohnRennie It would help if someone can quantify this because I actually see increased spherical aberration when I try to change a biconcave lens to a meniscus lens (but I do see your point when I change a biconvex lens to a meniscus lens - that's why I asked specifically about both cases).